# Fill in np.nan values with the value of the next occurrance of non np.nan value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to replace all nan values under a certain condition. If a value is nan, I would like to have it replaced with the date to the right side of it in it's specific list. If there are no date value to the right of the nan value, I would like to leave it as is.

Here is my starting dataframe.

```
mydf = [['2019-01-30', nan, nan, nan, '2020-03-09'],
        ['2018-11-29', nan, '2019-06-24', '2019-12-18', '2020-02-11'],
        [nan, nan, '2020-02-25', nan, nan]]
```

I would like this to end up looking like this.

```
mydf = [['2019-01-30', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-09', '2020-03-09'],
        ['2018-11-29', '2019-06-24', '2019-06-24', '2019-12-18', '2020-02-11'],
        ['2020-02-25', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-25', nan, nan]]
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
for i in range(0,len(mydf)):
    for j, k in enumerate(mydf[i]):
        if k is np.nan:
            mydf[i][j] = mydf[i][j+1]

mydf
```

but I receive an error. I can't seem to figure out how to stop the loop within each list once the remaining values in the list are all nan.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-247-3f0a1ce84ea0> in <module>
      2     for j, k in enumerate(mydf[i]):
      3         if k is np.nan:
----> 4             mydf[i][j] = mydf[i][j+1]
      5 
      6 mydf

IndexError: list index out of range

mydf
    [['2020-02-25', '2020-02-25', '2020-02-25', nan, nan],
     ['2018-11-29', nan, '2019-06-24', '2019-12-18', '2020-02-11'],
     ['2019-01-30', nan, nan, nan, '2020-03-09']]
```

Comment: How do you fill the last column if there is not "right side"?

Comment: You want `df.bfill(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as desired.

```
mydf.fillna(method='ffill') 
mydf.fillna(method='bfill')
```

No need to do loop here.

Comment: I think OP wants "bfill" method. Also I think axis should be set

Comment: This was very helpful. I was able to get the dataframe to look how I wanted by using mydf.fillna(method='bfill'). I transposed my original dataframe and applied the method then transposed it back again.

Comment: Like I said in the comments, you just want `mydf.bfill(axis=1)` @asiu321

Comment: Even better, that made it a lot easier. Thank you again for the help.